# How to keep a do...while loop from looping more than once while the condition is set to true

Tags: c++

Every other option works except for option 1. After a user has input name and account type. It enters into an infinite loop. How do I set my do-while loop to fix this behavior? Please can someone help me fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Bank{

    //data members
private:
    string customer_name;
    double account_number;
    string type_of_account;
    double account_balance;
    double balance;


    //function declaration
public:
    void assignInitialValue(void);
    void deposit();
    void makeWithdrawal();
    void displayNameAndBalance();
    void displayDetails();
};

//function definitions
void Bank::assignInitialValue(void){
    cout<<"Welcome to Our Bank."<<endl;
    cout<<"To open an Account with us,please supply the following details"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your name in full"<<endl;
    cin>>customer_name;
    cout<<"Choose an Account type"<<endl;
    cin>>type_of_account;
    cout<<"Enter your Account Number"<<endl;
    cin>>account_number;
    cout<<"Enter an Amount you will like to open this account with"<<endl;
    cin>>account_balance;
    cout<<"Thank you for banking with us";
}

void Bank::deposit(void){
    scout<<"Enter the amount you want to deposit"<<endl;
    double deposit_amount = 0.0;
    cin>>deposit_amount;
    account_balance = account_balance + deposit_amount;
    cout<<"Your new balance is now:"<<account_balance;
    balance = account_balance;
}

void Bank::makeWithdrawal(void){
    int withdrawal_amount;
    cout<<"\nBalance Amount = "<<balance;
    cout<<"\nPlease Enter the Amount you want to withdraw:-";
    cin>>withdrawal_amount;
    if(!(withdrawal_amount > balance))
        balance=balance-withdrawal_amount;
    else
    {
        cout<<"Insufficient Balance";
    }
    cout<<"Your Available Balance is:"<<balance;
}
void Bank::displayDetails(void)
{
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<setw(50)<<"CUSTOMER DETAILS"<<endl;
    cout<<setw(50)<<"Customer Name "<<customer_name<<endl;
    cout<<setw(50)<<"Account Number."<<account_number<<endl;
    cout<<setw(50)<<"Account Type"<<type_of_account<<endl;
    cout<<setw(50)<<"Balance"<<balance<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bank app;
    int Activity_code;

    do
    {
        cout<<"\n\nAvailable Transactions\n\n";
        cout<<"1)  To create Account with us press 1\n";
        cout<<"2)  To make deposit press 2\n";
        cout<<"3)  To make Withdrawal press 3\n";
        cout<<"4)  To Display All Details press 4\n";
        cout<<"5)  EXIT\n";
        cout<<"Please enter an Activity choice :-";

        cin>>Activity_code;


        switch(Activity_code)
        {
            case 1: app.assignInitialValue();
                break;
            case 2: app.deposit();
                break;
            case 3: app.makeWithdrawal();
                break;
            case 4: app.displayDetails();
                break;
            case 5: goto terminate;
        }
    }while(true);
terminate:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please state what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Seriously dude, no one will *ever* want to read your code if you can't format it in a way that is comprehendible. Done it for you this time, but please, make a point to take the time. You may not think it matters, but when you're pouring over a hundred-thousand lines across a dozen source files, it makes a difference.

Comment: Please specify the portion where you are getting collapsed.

Comment: If you don't want something to loop more than once - ***don't loop***!

Comment: A "loop that loops only once" is called an `if` statement.

Comment: In your logic, you do want a loop since after someone performs one transaction, you need to do it and then wait for someone to enter the next transaction. The cin>>  should wait for user input. So not really clear where the problem is. I am deleting my answer since on closer inspection, it is another way to achieve what your code does.

Comment: @immibis That's true for a while loop. But a do-while that runs only once is just sequential code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally on topic (a rarity for me) so I might as well make this an answer.

`>>` only reads in 1 whitespace delimited token, aka 1 word, so `cin >>customer_name;` is going to have a lot of trouble with "John Smith." This will leave "Smith" in the stream to be parsed into `type_of_account` and that will leave the stream in a very bad state that will result in an infinite loop if not cleaned up with `cin.clear` and `cin.ignore`. I recommend reading up on `std::getline` to read more than one word at a time.

Comment: user4581301 cin.ignore() helped me fix this to a great extent but the problem is that when i try to output say customer name it is blank,when i try to print account_number, the customer name appears. Can't seem to fix that. Thanx for your input.

Comment: @HenryNnonyelu What's likely happening here is `cin.ignore` is eating up a left-over line feed from hitting enter. Don't focus on `ignore`. Use it for clean-up after an error. What you really want is to be able to read whole lines of user input in one go. For that you need `std::getline`

Answer (score 0):

There's trouble ahead if your input is unexpected, e.g. your program expects a double but your input is something that can't be converted properly. In this case the buffer of cin doesn't get cleared and your loop has input without asking you again, thus repeating over and over.

I suggest to use strings for input and do the conversion after reading.
Here is the modified function assignInitialValue():

```
void Bank::assignInitialValue(void){
  cout<<"Welcome to Our Bank."<<endl;
  cout<<"To open an Account with us,please supply the following details"<<endl;
  cout<<"Enter your name in full"<<endl;
  cin>>customer_name;
  cout<<"Choose an Account type"<<endl;
  cin>>type_of_account;
  cout<<"Enter your Account Number"<<endl;
  string temp1;
  cin>>temp1;
  istringstream convert1(temp1);
  convert1>>account_number;
  cout<<"Enter an Amount you will like to open this account with"<<endl;
  string temp2;
  cin>>temp2;
  istringstream convert2(temp2);
  convert2>>account_balance;
  cout<<"Thank you for banking with us";
}
```

Note that this is far away from being perfect because it still doesn't validate your input.